# How long does it take specific types of metal to heat up in the sun?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, thermal-conductivity

I'm wondering how long it would take different metals -- for the sake of this question I'll say steel -- to heat up in the sun. Assume it was an 80 degree day and a piece of steel was sitting in a wide open area with the sun beating down on it continuously, how long would it take for it to reach 250 degrees Celsius (482 degrees Fahrenheit) if at all?

Comment: Are the metals coated, do we have a mass to work with? Angle the sun is making with the ground? Your query will need a lot more specifics to be answered uniquely.

Comment: The radiation temperature of direct sunlight in vacuum at Earth orbit is about 120 degrees Celsius, so even neglecting absorption by atmosphere and convective cooling, unless the metal is near the focus of a mirror or lens concentrating the sunlight, you'll have to wait about five billion years for the sun to expand enough to more than double its luminosity. Actually predicting the temperature as a function of time sounds like it would be a fairly nasty system of partial differential equations for a real world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a lot of things, but basically you're looking at [blackbody radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) and heat loss by conduction to the atmosphere. Let's keep it really simple and forget the atmosphere, so we can ignore conduction. Since heat coming from the sun is by radiation only, we have to use $\frac{Q} {\Delta t}=σeAT$ ①. $\frac{Q_\text{net}} {\Delta t}$ is power input (watts) from the sun less rate of energy lost from the object. You didn't tell us anything about the area, or condition of the steel, so you'd have to find or be told its area and emissivity e. We also need to know the area of the steel exposed to the sun. One thing we also need: We need to know how much heat was required to raise the temperature of the steel: $Q=mc\Delta T$ ②, so we need to know the mass (specific heat capacity of steel c = $0.466 \frac{J}{kg*°K}$). To find the heat, plug in your values for $T_2$ and $T_1$, make sure to convert these to kelvin.

Then you can solve $\Delta t = \frac{Q}{σeA(T^4_2−T^4_1)}$ ③, plug in the Q that you found above, as well as the emissivity, area, and $T_2$ and $T_1$, and you'll get how long it takes to do this (in a vacuum).

It'll take a bit longer if you don't lose the atmosphere, since it'll also have a net loss of heat via conduction to the atmosphere (the atmosphere is less efficient at absorbing the radiative input from the sun than the steel probably is, effectively its emissivity e is much lower than the steel). But I challenge you to try an experiment: go out and find a large piece of steel laying in full sunlight on an 80°F day, a truss bridge will do nicely. Go out and measure the temperature of the metal (thermometer, or just touching it). Does it seem reasonable to conclude that it will ever reach 482°F?

Here's your homework, I'll leave it to you to figure out what numbers to plug into ② and ③ to find out how long it would take your steel to heat up from 80°F to 482°F while floating in an earth-radius orbit (allowing you to use Earth standard solar power per area inputs) while always facing flat to the sun. What happens when the steel reaches this temperature? Will the temperature stabilize or continue to increase (Keep in mind that a blackbody absorber is also a radiator)?

If you need a little more practice, please see [this article](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/14-7-radiation/)